# Alternative CSS for specific URLs

Tags: css

How can I make an Alternative CSS file only be applied to specific URLs? for instance, only to all pages after "/SitePages".

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do it.  One option is to add a JavaScript file to the master page (OR use a site/web custom action) that will add the CSS file to the head of a page being loaded.

the JavaScript file would have code something like:

```
if(window.location.toLowerCase() === 'something in the url as lowercase text'){
    // variables
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        linktag = document.createElement('link');

    // linktag attributes
    linktag.rel = 'stylesheet';
    linktag.type = 'text/css';
    linktag.href = 'url of css file';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild('linktag');
}
```

If you really want to make it fancy, you can make that code a function with parameters, then just call the function as many times as necessary for each individual url.

When using a custom action, I've always used this library to register and unregister them.  https://gist.github.com/iOnline247/db5d03c1fde98a749fbd